# Thinking sphinx condition in HAS

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I have an index in which I want to filter on some attributes based on some condition.

The below structure is working perfectly fine

```
Class A
attr_accessible :vaild_date
belongs_to: B
define_index 'index_for_a' do
  indexes ...
  ...
  has B.C.plant_id, :as => :plant_id
end
end

class B
  has_many: C
end

class C
  attr_accessible :plant_id,:month_timestamps
end
```

Now my C class has many rows. I want to have plant_id only for the rows where

```
C.month_timestamps = A.valid_date
```

Please suggest some approach to achieve this. Being new to thinking_sphinx, I am not able to properly use the conditions and clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a

```
  #Assuming Class C is stored in db as Cs
  where "Cs.month_timestamps = valid_date"
```

to your `define_index` block like this

```
define_index 'index_for_a' do
  indexes ...
  ...
  has B.C.plant_id, :as => :plant_id

  join B.C
  #Assuming Class C is stored in db as Cs
  where "Cs.month_timestamps = valid_date"
end
```

**Update**

Updated answer with edit suggested by [CrazyDiv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2472056/crazydiv)

**Update**

Try something like this

```
  has  "IFNULL(Cs.plant_id,0)", :as => :plant_id
```

Comment: Thanks works great. Could you also tell how to add a nil condition. i.e. I need b.c.plant_id to be 0 when there's no row in b.c.

Comment: anything that goes within the double quotes is plain SQL syntax. For example, you can write `has "B.C.plant_id as plant_id"`, just the way you did it with `where`. The same can be used with `indexes`   also. So I am sure you can figure out how to do that. `ts` actually generates the `SQL` statement and dumps it in a file. You can inspect that to learn more.

Comment: Thanks got it. Could you please help me in adding nil condition. I want plant_id to be set as zero when there is no row in C. I was trying with CASE WHEN but with no luck

Comment: no luck.results are still the same, I think due to where condition. I also tried adding Cs.month_timestamps= null or C.month_timestamps = valid_date. any suggestions?